# Understanding foldLeft with Map instead of List

Tags: scala, dictionary, language-concepts, foldleft

I fould like to understand how `foldLeft` works for Maps. I do understand how it works if I have a List and call on it foldLeft with a zero-element and a function:

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3)
list1.foldLeft(0)((a,b) => a + b)
```

Where I add the zero-element `0` with the first element of `list1` and then add the second element of `list1` and so on. So output becomes the new input and the first input is the zero-element.

Now I got the code

```
val map1 = Map(1 -> 2.0, 3 -> 4.0, 5 -> 6.2) withDefaultValue 0.0
val map2 = Map(0 -> 3.0, 3 -> 7.0) withDefaultValue 0.0
def myfct(terms: Map[Int, Double], term: (Int, Double)): Map[Int, Double] = ???

map1.foldLeft(map2)(myfct)
```

1. So my first element here is a `Tuple2`, but since `map2` is a `Map` and not a `Tuple2`, what is the zero-element?
2. When we had a `List`, namely `list1`, we always "took the next element in `list1`". What is the "next element in `map1`? Is it another pair of `map1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context, you can think of a `Map` as a list of tuples. You can create a list like this: `List(1 -> 2.0, 3 -> 4.0, 5 -> 6.2)`, and call `foldLeft` on it (that is more or less exactly what `Map.foldLeft` does). If you understand how `foldLeft` works with lists, then now you know how it works with Maps too :)
To answer your specific questions:

1. The first parameter of `foldLeft` can be of any type. You could pass in a `Map` instead of an `Int` in your first example too. It does not have to be of the same type as elements of the collection you are processing (although, it could be), as you have in your first example, nor does it need to be the same type as the collection itself, as you have it in the last example.
   Consider this for the sake of example:

   ```
    List(1,2,3,4,5,6).foldLeft(Map.empty[String,Int]) { case(map,elem) => 
      map + (elem.toString -> elem) 
    }
   ```

This produces the same result as `list.map { x => x.toString -> x }.toMap`. As you can see, the first parameter here is a `Map`, that is neither `List` nor an `Int`.

The type you pass to `foldLeft` is also the type it returns, and the type that the function you pass in returns. It is not "element zero".
`foldLeft` will pass that parameter to your reducer function, along with the first element of the list. Your function will combine the two elements, and produce a new value of the same type as the first param. That value is passed in again, again with the second element ... etc.
Perhaps, inspecting the signature of `foldLeft` would be helpful:

```
   foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

Here `A` is the type of your collection elements, and `B` can be anything, the only requirement is that the four places where it appears have the same type.

Here is another example, that is (almost) equivalent to `list.mkString(",")`:

```
   List(1,2,3,4,5,6).foldLeft("") { 
     case("", i) => i.toString
     case(s,i) => s + "," + i
   }
```

2. As I explained in the beginning, a map in this context is a kind of a list (a sequence rather). Just like "we always took the next element of the list" when we dealt with lists, we will take the "next element of the map" in this case. You said it yourself, the elements of the map are tuples, so that's what the type of the next element will be:

   ```
    Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
     .foldLeft("") { 
       case("", (key,value)) => key + "->" + value
       case(s, (key,value)) => s + ", " + key + "->" + value
     }
   ```

Comment: 1) Thanks for the really great post! 2) "as you have it in the last example." seems wrong to me: Here `A` is a `Tuple2`, so not a `Map`. Please correct or comment. 3) Why `case(map,elem)` and not simply `(map,elem)` in your first example? 4) Neither `scala.collection.immutable.Map` nor `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable` seem to implement `foldLeft`. How come all these collection have `foldLeft`?

Comment: I think 4) is wrong, however I am still a little confused due to all those different implementations...

Comment: From http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/collections it seems to me Maps are not Lists. Are they internally implemented as Lists of Tuples? That's what your post suggests, but is it true? (I do not know how to check out the source code of `Map`.)

Comment: If you look at the Scala doc, you'll see (for example) for `foldLeft` on Map "Definition Classes
TraversableOnce → GenTraversableOnce" telling you where it is defined (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B). Also at the top of a class's scaladoc is a link to the source. Again, for Map, this is https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L1

Comment: And, no, they're not implemented as `List`s of `Tuple`s, but there are ways of accessing the content as `Tuple`s. Which is what `foldLeft` does (by way of `foreach` which uses `iterator` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@iterator:Iterator[(A,B)]) which as that page says, has to be implemented by concrete subclasses of `Map`...

Comment: @Make42 you are correct, Maps are not Lists, and they are not implemented as Lists either. All I said was that _in this context_ you can _look_ at the map as a _if it were_ a list of tuples. The reason you can do that is because, even though maps aren't lists, they some some of the properties with them, such as, for instance, being able to scan through the sequence of elements, which is important in this case.

Comment: @Make42 to answer your questions:  By "as you have it in your last example" I was referring to your passing `map2` to `foldLeft`. `A` is a tuple there, but `B` in your case was a `Map`.  Re. `case(map,elem)`  can be replace with just `(map, elem)` in this particular case, you are correct. I am just used to writing `case` in this context because it is more general. `foldLeft` is implemented in some superclass of `Map`, `TraversableOnce` I think ...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the signature of the `foldLeft` operation is as shown:

```scala
foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

The resulting type of the operation is `B`. So, this answers your first question:

> So my first element here is a Tuple2, but since map2 is a Map and not
> a Tuple2, what is the zero-element?

The zero-element is whatever you want to output from the `foldLeft`. It could be an `Int` or a `Map` or anything else for that matter.

`op` in the function signature (i.e the second argument), is how you would like to operate on that for each element of map1, which is a `(key,value)` pair, or another way of writing it is as `key -> value`.

Let's try and understand it by building it up with more simpler operations.

```scala
val map1 = Map(1 -> 1.0, 4 -> 4.0, 5 -> 5.0) withDefaultValue 0.0
val map2 = Map(0 -> 0.0, 3 -> 3.0) withDefaultValue 0.0

// Here we're just making the output an Int
// So we just add the first element of the key-value pair.
def myOpInt(z: Int, term: (Int, Double)): Int = {
  z + term._1
}

// adds all the first elements of the key-value pairs of map1 together
map1.foldLeft(0)(myOpInt)  // ... output is 10
// same as above, but for map2 ...
map2.foldLeft(0)(myOpInt) // ... output is 3
```

Now, taking it to the next step by using a zero element (`z`) as an existing map...we would essentially add elements to that map we are using as `z`.

```scala
val map1 = Map(1 -> 1.0, 4 -> 4.0, 5 -> 5.0) withDefaultValue 0.0
val map2 = Map(0 -> 0.0, 3 -> 3.0) withDefaultValue 0.0

// Here z is a Map of Int -> Double
// We expect a pair of (Int, Double) as the terms to fold left with z
def myfct(z: Map[Int, Double], term: (Int, Double)): Map[Int, Double] = {
  z + term
}

map1.foldLeft(map2)(myfct) 
// output is Map(0 -> 0.0, 5 -> 5.0, 1 -> 1.0, 3 -> 3.0, 4 -> 4.0)
// i.e. same elements of both maps concatenated together, albeit out of order, since Maps don't guarantee order ...
```

> When we had a List, namely list1, we always "took the next element in
> list1". What is the "next element in map1? Is it another pair of map1?

Yes, it's another key-value pair `(k,v)` in `map1`.